# JavaFX, FXMLLoader.setController(controller) doesn't load scene

Tags: javafx, fxml, netbeans-8

Keep freezing when on setController. It doesn't load scene when user and password are enter

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.fxml.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GiantsLoginController {

public String dataName, serverName, password;
public int num;

private Connection connect = null;
private Statement stmt = null;

private boolean userPass, connected;

private Connections connection;


@FXML
private ComboBox<String> sType;
@FXML
public TextField dbName;
@FXML
private TextField sName;
@FXML
private Button loginB;
@FXML
private PasswordField sPassword;
@FXML
private Pane paneL;
@FXML
private GridPane gPane;
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> uType;


ObservableList<String> sLists = FXCollections.observableArrayList("MySQL LOCAL", 
        "MYSQL REMOTE", "SQL SERVER LOCAL", "SQL SERVER");
ObservableList<String> uList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Player", 
        "Admin");



@FXML
public void initialize() {
    sType.setItems(sLists);
    uType.setItems(uList);
}

@FXML
public void loginBClick (Event event) {
    if (isAllFieldFillup()) {

        switch(uType.getValue().trim()) {
            case "Admin":
                if (connectCheck()) {
                    try {

                          changeStage(GiantsLogin.getPrimaryStage());

                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            case "Player": 
                if (connectCheck()) {
                    try {

                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

public void changeStage(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    GiantsAdminController controller = new GiantsAdminController("Hello World!");
    FXMLLoader loader = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("GiantsAdmin.fxml"));
    loader.setController(controller);
    stage.hide();
    stage.setScene(new Scene((Pane) loader.load()));
    stage.show();
}

public void closeConnection () {

    if (connect != null) {
        try {
            stmt.close();
            connect.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {

        }
    }
}

public boolean connectCheck() {
    connected = false;

    dataName = dbName.getText();
    serverName = sName.getText();
    password = sPassword.getText();


    switch (sType.getValue()) {
        case "MySQL LOCAL":
            num = 1;
            break;
        case "MYSQL REMOTE":
            num = 2;
            break;
        case "SQL SERVER LOCAL":
            num = 3;
            break;
        case "SQL SERVER":
            num = 4;
            break;
        default:

    }

    if (connect == null) {
        connect = Connections.getconnect(num, dataName, serverName, password);
    }

    if (connect == null ) {
        System.out.println("Still no connection");
    }

    if (stmt == null) {
        try {
            stmt = connect.createStatement();
            connected = true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Alert notify = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            notify.setTitle("Blank filed");
            notify.setHeaderText(null);
            notify.setContentText("Incorrect login.");
            notify.showAndWait();

            connected = false;
        }


    }
    return connected;
}

private boolean isAllFieldFillup() {
    boolean allInfo;
    if (sType.getValue().equals("server type") && dbName.getText().isEmpty()
            && sName.getText().isEmpty() && sPassword.getText().isEmpty()) {
        Alert notify = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        notify.setTitle("Blank filed");
        notify.setHeaderText(null);
        notify.setContentText("You are missing some information.");
        notify.showAndWait();

        allInfo = false;
    }
    else {
        allInfo = true;
    }
    return allInfo;
}

}
```

> This is where I open a new scene and set my controller so I can be
>   able to access it in new scene. But it aways frozed when I put the
>   user name and password and click login.
>
> ```
> public void changeStage(Stage stage) throws IOException {
>     GiantsAdminController controller = new GiantsAdminController("Hello World!");
>     FXMLLoader loader = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("GiantsAdmin.fxml"));
>     loader.setController(controller);
>     stage.hide();
>     stage.setScene(new Scene((Pane) loader.load()));
>     stage.show();
> }
> ```
>
> This is where I am calling the changeStage method this method
>
> ```
> public void loginBClick (Event event) {
>     if (isAllFieldFillup()) {
>
>         switch(uType.getValue().trim()) {
>             case "Admin":
>                 if (connectCheck()) {
>                     try {
>
>                           changeStage(GiantsLogin.getPrimaryStage());
>
>                     }
>                     catch (Exception e) {
>
>                     }
>                 }
>             case "Player": 
>                 if (connectCheck()) {
>                     try {
>
>                     }
>                     catch (Exception e) {
>
>                     }
>                 }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This is my main class
>
> ```
> import java.io.IOException;
> import javafx.application.Application;
> import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
> import javafx.scene.*;
>
> public class GiantsLogin extends Application {
>
> private static Stage stage;
>
> @Override
> public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
>     setPrimaryStage(stage);
>     Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("GiantsLogin.fxml"));
>     Scene scene = new Scene(root);
>     scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
>     stage.setScene(scene);
>     stage.setTitle("Giants Login");
>     stage.show();
> }
>
> public static void setPrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage) {
>     stage = primaryStage;
> }
>
> public static Stage getPrimaryStage() {
>     return stage;
> }
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     launch(args);
> }
>
> }
> ```
>
> This is my second window: This is the window that supposed to open
>   when the user name and pass are correct.
>
> ```
> import java.io.IOException;
> import java.sql.Statement;
> import javafx.collections.*;
> import javafx.event.Event;
> import javafx.fxml.*;
> import javafx.scene.Node;
> import javafx.scene.Parent;
> import javafx.scene.Scene;
> import javafx.scene.control.*;
> import javafx.stage.Stage;
>
> public class GiantsAdminController {
> @FXML
> private Button connect = null;
> private boolean connected;
>
> private Statement stmt;
>
> @FXML
> private TextField aRank;
>
> public GiantsAdminController(String message) {
>     System.out.println("You said: " + message);
> }
>
> public GiantsAdminController() {
> }
>
> ObservableList<String> sLists = FXCollections.observableArrayList("MySQL LOCAL", 
>         "MYSQL REMOTE", "SQL SERVER LOCAL", "SQL SERVER");
> @FXML
> public void initialize() {
>     serverType.setItems(sLists);
> }
>
> @FXML
> public void clearBClick (Event event) {
>     aRank.clear();
>     aName.clear();
>     aPosition.clear();
>     aSchool.clear();
>     aAge.clear();
>     aWar.clear();
> }
>
>
> @FXML
> public void SingOutClick(Event event) throws IOException {
>
>     Parent giantsLogin = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/giants/GiantsLogin.fxml"));
>
>     Scene gLScene = new Scene(giantsLogin);
>     gLScene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
>     stage.setScene(gLScene); 
>     stage.show();
> }
>  }
> ```

I have try everything to solve this problem, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the use of a static load function on the FXMLLoader.
Try this modification (not tested).

```
public void changeStage(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    GiantsAdminController controller = new GiantsAdminController("Hello World!");
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("GiantsAdmin.fxml"));
    loader.setController(controller);
    stage.hide();
    stage.setScene(new Scene((Pane) loader.load()));
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: I just did that. And now it's not  freezing any more. However the second scene is not opening

Comment: BTW, I noticed that you didn't call changeStage() method when the user is palyer

Comment: That right. I just want to make sure it's work for admin first. Bust still it's not get the second scene. Can you please look at it again and to see why the scones scene it's not opening. Please